# How to check permissions on folders in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, databricks

I want to simply check the permissions that I have on a buckets/folders/files in AWS S3. Something like:

ls -l

Sounds like it should be pretty easy but I cannot find any information on the subject. I just want to know if I have read access to a content, or if I can load a file locally without trying to load the data, to have an "Error Code: 403 Forbidden" thrown at me.

Note: I am using databricks and want to check the permission from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the permissions using the command,

> aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket my-bucket --key index.html

You acl for each object can vary across your bucket.

More documentation at,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object-acl.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice, so that command works on single files. Do you know of a way to check the entire folder? Or do I have to implement the check recursively myself?
Thanks!

Comment: SInce the permissions vary by object. S3 also does not have anything like folder. Everything is considered as individual objects. You can do listing on the bucket with aws s3 ls s3://bucket/prefix --recursive and pipe it to the above command, should give permissions all the objects. You can do optimizations to avoid duplicate permission listing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to grant access to objects in Amazon S3.

Permissions can be granted on a **whole bucket**, or a path within a bucket, via a [Bucket Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html).

Permissions can also be granted to an **IAM User or Role**, giving that specific user/role permissions similar to a bucket policy.

Then there are permissions on the **object itself**, such as making it publicly readable.

So, there is no simple way to say "what are the permissions on this particular object" because it depends who you are. Also, the policies can restrict by IP address and time of day, so there isn't always one answer.

You could use the [IAM Policy Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) to test whether a certain call (eg `PutObject` or `GetObject`) would work for a given user.

Some commands in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) come with a `--dryrun` option that will simply test *whether* the command would have worked, without actually executing the command.

Or, sometimes it is just easiest to try to access the object and see what happens!

Comment: Yes, but I want the permissions with respect to me, to know what I can and cannot do. But yeah, as of now, my approach has been to try and see what happens ahaha.
Thanks!